# How to boot into recovery mode on Catalina?

Tags: macos, recovery, startup

I see that the instructions for booting into Recovery Mode is to press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> after reboot  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

> How to start up from macOS Recovery
> Turn on your Mac and immediately press and hold these two keys: Command (⌘) and R.  Need help?
> Release the keys when you see an Apple logo, spinning globe, or other startup screen.

I have tried those instructions repeatedly - and have not been able to get into Recovery Mode. I had been able to do so in the past - to do

```
  sudo csrutil enable
```

I now want to get out of SIP but can not because the Recovery Mode will not start.

**Update** Responding to @bmike 's comment .  For the following screen - I have tried the following:

- Press and hold <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> before it appeared [and until the *normal* boot/logon screen shows up]
- Press and hold <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> before *anything* appears [and until the *normal* boot/logon screen shows up]
- Press and release <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> repeatedly from after reboot

[image]

None of these affect the boot sequence: I end up in normal logon screen in normal boot mode.

**Second update** Here is the result of `sudo diskutil list`

```
$sudo diskutil list
Password:
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     553.6 GB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.7 MB    disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                535.6 MB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s5
```

This is a 2020 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Which of the three screens do you see in step 2 of the linked article when you hold command and R?

Comment: We need to see your internal disk partitions / volumes.  Boot normally and open Terminal.  Issue the command "diskutil list" and copy / paste the results to your question.  If you cannot boot, create a bootable installer USB for Catalina and boot with that by holding Option key.  Then mount the internal disk, run a first aid in Disk Utility on the internal disk.  Copy / Paste the diskutil info.  Suspect recovery mode partition is damaged or missing.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Added  the `diskutil list`: I had actually looked at it previously and it seems normal

Comment: @bmike  I updated the question. lmk is that the info you were requesting

Comment: Which Mac (model and year) are you using?  If you have a 2010 or later Mac, try Internet Recovery - press `Cmd-Opt-R`

Comment: Your recovery partition is probably hosed up.  Try Internet Recovery, you should also be able to see/boot the partition when you hold `Opt` while booting.  If you don't then it's probably corrupt.  A reinstall will fix it.  I've personally never relied on it and instead opted for Internet Recovery.

Comment: I would create a bootable flash installer and reinstall over your existing system. There have been ways to install just the recovery volume but it’s easier to just reinstall.

Comment: I can not wait 40+ minutes for this at this time, heavy work and school tasks. Thanks for the insights, given the apparent magnitude of the adjustments i will have to delay this at least a week.

Comment: Super updates - so it’s clear Catalina has nothing to do with your process - you’ve just got bad hardware or a bad layout of the drive. I’ll put my “go to” way to fix this - install OS onto an entirely different drive or erase yours - maybe someone knows how to pick apart the specific failure, but the path forward is now clear to me.

Comment: @bmike  What does the `diskutil list` say to you? Is there anything else that would further  illuminate what is wrong?  I won't have time to do a full reinstall until probably Christmas

Comment: Installing catalina on a fresh external drive is the winning move in that case. You could boot to the other OS and try repairing the SSD - make sure it’s without errors or those errors are fixed, then try running the installer I added after the - - - in my answer.

Comment: When I want to boot to **macOS Recovery** from a running occurrence of **macOS**, I use the following _compound command_ from **Terminal** on the **Desktop**: `sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"; sleep 2; sudo reboot` Then before I reboot from **macOS Recovery**, in **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu, run: `nvram -d recovery-boot-mode` The latter is not necessary in some versions of **macOS**, however, it doesn't hurt either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get a backup and not worry about the recovery partition until you have time for an erase install or some processes that can take an hour (or more if you don’t have the Catalina installer up to date and downloaded).

Your disk layout is generally good - no issues that are easy to diagnose and fix. In the mean time make sure all your data / backups are current. When you’re ready, you will want to get an external drive and erase the drive completely (not just erasing a volume, but complete erase per this page)

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496

Many people will select Macintosh HD and erase it, rather than erasing the container, so be sure you follow the “How to erase your disk” part and not “How to erase a volume on your disk” portion.

Then run the installer to install on the blank drive - once that is done, you can hold the option key to test things boot, migrate data in from backup and make the call if and when you do the erase on the internal drive.

---

If you wanted to try a half measure, delete any old installers you have (including stand alone bootable installers) and get a copy of Catalina fresh from the App Store and run that installer one time. It might fix the built in recovery partition, but I really don’t like messing with things at this point. Yes, we could fix your one issue - but it shouldn’t have broken and what else might be broken as well that you don’t know about. Better to erase IMO.